# POSTDATA Wrong JSON format?

Tags: php, ajax, json

I have an AJAX request which sends JSON data to process.php, but it sends the parameters in the wrong format, x-www-form-urlencoded. I would like to send with JSON format.

Here is my code, I don't know where the problem is.

```
 $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          url:"process.php",
          contentType: "application/json",
          dataType: "json",
          async: true,
          data: {
              country: json[i][0],
              competition: json[i][1],
              club: json[i][2]},

            success: function(){ alert("data")},
          error: function(){ /*alert("error")*/}
        });
    }
});
```

The result of the post request in Tamper data:

> Host=localhost User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0 Accept=application/json, text/javascript, /; q=0.01 Accept-Language=en_EN,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3 Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate Content-Type=application/json; charset=UTF-8 X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest Referer=localhost/football/process.php Content-Length=61 Connection=keep-alive Pragma=no-cache Cache-Control=no-cache POSTDATA=country=America&competition=Copa+Libertado&club=Boca+Juniors

Why are my parameters sent in x-www-form-urlencoded format instead of JSON?

Comment: `dataType` tells json what to expect BACK from the server. it has nothing to do with what you're sending. if you want to send json, you'll have to do yourself with JSON.stringify()

Comment: I must add JSON.stringify at process.php right? Because I would like to add all data to mysql database.

Comment: no, because that's on the server. if you want to SEND json to server, there's no point in doing it at the server - that's too late. it has to be done in the client (e.g. JS).

Comment: And what can I do now? I can't change the format in the client.

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify(blahblahblah)`

Comment: at the ajax request? like: data: JSON.stringify( {
              country: json[i][0],
              competition: json[i][1],
              club: json[i][2]} )

Comment: thanks a lot, its good now!